# Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, automated testing, and SVN

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, developer-tools

We have an HTML designer who is not a developer but needs to modify .aspx files from our ASP.NET 2.0 projects from time to time in order to get CSS to work properly with them.  Currently, this involves giving her the .aspx page by itself, which she opens and edits via Visual Studio 2008 (her computer used to be a developer's).  I'm considering getting her set up with Visual Web Developer 2010 Express and Subversion access so she can be more independent, but I wanted to make sure VS Express will work properly with what we do.  So:

- Does VWD 2010 Express support automated tests?
- If no to the above, what happens when it opens a solution file that includes a test project, modifies it, and saves it?
- Are there any potential snags with setting up AnkhSVN with VWD 2010 Express?

Comment: Should you really be worried about front end testing for when a designer changes the markup for a page?

Comment: The tests are for the back-end data stuff, not the front end that the designer would be modifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Does VWD 2010 Express support automated tests?*

No, the [Express versions do not support test automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424229/unit-testing-in-visual-c-sharp-2010-express/3425508#3425508). You can [implement external tools](https://web.archive.org/web/20120706040421/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2008/03/06/asp-net-mvc-test-framework-integration-demo.aspx), such as NUnit and run the tests outside of VS. If your shop is using Team Edition and all the features available in that, the test solutions (just like deployment solutions) will not load.

> *If no to the above, what happens when it opens a solution file that includes a test project, modifies it, and saves it?*

The project(s) that are not supported by the Express edition will be unloaded, and show up in Solution Explorer as greyed out and "unavailable". They will not be removed unless the user removes the projects and saves the solution.  But this will not mess anything up for other developers on the project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think AnkhSVN will work as it is an add-on and MS don't like add-ons working in the express SKUs. Testing-wise, I seem to recall that TestDriven.NET will work with the express SKUs -- Microsoft thanked the developer by booting him from the MVP program.

All that said, you should probably look into continuous integration as that is a bit more effective a backstop than having local unit tests the design types won't understand. Then they can use whatever tools they like so long as they can svn commit things at the end of the day.